# Laravel - proplem about creating "delete" button and display confirmation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, delete-row

I have index.blade.php as :

```
@extends('backend.layouts.app')
@section('title')
Danh sách sinh viên
@endsection
@section('content')
@if(session()->has('status'))
<div class="callout callout-info">
     {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
<div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
               {{csrf_field()}}
              <h3 class="box-title">Danh sách sinh viên</h3> <br>
              <a href="{{route('sinhvien.create')}}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user-plus"></i> Bấm vào đây để thêm dữ liệu </a>
              <div class="box-tools">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
                  <input type="text" name="table_search" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Search">
                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
              <table class="table table-hover">
                <tbody><tr>
                  <th>MSSV</th>
                  <th>Họ Tên</th>
                  <th>Ngày sinh</th>
                  <th>Ngày đăng kí </th>
                  <th>Giới tính</th>
                  <th>SĐT</th>
                  <th>CMND</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Quê quán</th>
                  <th>Sồ tiền TK</th>
                  <th>Phòng</th>
                  <th>Hành động</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach($dssv as $sinhvien)
                <tr>
                  <td>{{$sinhvien->sv_ma}}</td>
                  <td>{{$sinhvien->sv_hoTen}}</td>
                  <td>{{$sinhvien->sv_ngaySinh}}</td>
                  <td>{{$sinhvien->sv_ngayDk}}</td>
                   <td><?php echo ($sinhvien->sv_gioiTinh==1)?'Nam':'Nữ' ?></td>
                  <td>{{$sinhvien->sv_dienThoai}}</td>
                  <td>{{$sinhvien->sv_CMND}}</td>
                  <td>{{$sinhvien->sv_Email}}</td>
                  <td>{{$sinhvien->sv_queQuan}}</td>
                  <td>{{$sinhvien->sv_soTienTK}}</td>
                  <td>{{$sinhvien->phong->p_ten}}</td>
                  <td><button class="btn btn-default"><a href="{{ route('sinhvien.edit',['sinhvien' => $sinhvien->sv_id])}}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i></a></button>
                      <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-danger" value="{{$id=$sinhvien->sv_id}}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o"></i>
                      </button>

                  </td>
                </tr>
                    <!-- /.modal -->

                @endforeach
              </tbody></table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
  <div class="modal modal-danger fade"  id="modal-danger">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Cảnh báo</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Bạn có muốn xóa sinh viên <?php echo $id?> không?</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Đóng</button>
                <form  method="POST" action="{{ route('sinhvien.destroy',['sinhvien' => $id])}}">{{ method_field("DELETE")}}
                       {{csrf_field()}}<input type="submit" name="btnxoa" class="btn btn-danger" value="Xóa"></input></form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>  


@endsection
```

As you see when i click button from source :"

```
 <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-danger" value="{{$id=$sinhvien->sv_id}}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o"></i>
                          </button>
```

"
Then,it will display a confirmation is "Do you want to delete this row ?" from source:

```
<div class="modal modal-danger fade"  id="modal-danger">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Warning</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you want to delete this row không? <?php echo $id?></p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Đóng</button>
                <form  method="POST" action="{{ route('sinhvien.destroy',['sinhvien' => $id])}}">{{ method_field("DELETE")}}
                       {{csrf_field()}}<input type="submit" name="btnxoa" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"></input></form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
```

My issue is that i get incorrect "sv_id" from (each rows that i want to delete). 
I need your help with better ideas. Thank you very much 
[Display incorrect sv_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX7VO.png)
[image]

Comment: Please add more context. It would be easier for us to help if we understood the variable names :) In the delete delete method of your controller add a return $request; or return $request('id'); to see the actual value that is being passed...

Comment: I have just updated Controller.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't send button value to bootstrap model. You should use data-id="{{$sinhvien->sv_id}}" instead of value="{{$id=$sinhvien->sv_id}}"

Then use Jquery onclickfunction on this button and get the value of data-id attribute. Set the value in model form and then trigger the model popup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my App\http\SinhvienController.php:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
           try
        {
            $sinhvien=Sinhvien::find($id);
            $sinhvien->delete();
            $phong=Phong::find($sinhvien->p_id);
            $phong->p_soNguoi=$phong->p_soNguoi-1;
            if($phong->p_trangThai==2)
            {
                $phong->p_trangThai=1;
            }
            $phong->save();
            return redirect(route('sinhvien.index'));
        }
        catch(QueryException $ex)
        {
            return response(['error'=> true ,'message'=> $ex->getMessage()],500);
        }
        //
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also show this delete confirmation message using jQuery or Javascript.

**HTML Section:**

```
<button class="btn btn-danger deleteBtn" sv_id="{{$sinhvien->sv_id}}">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o"></i>
</button>
```

**Javascript Section:**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.deleteBtn', function(){
    var sv_id = $(this).attr('sv_id');
    var confirmation = confirm('Do you want to delete this row '+sv_id);
    if(confirmation == true){
    //Do whatever you want
    } else {
    return false;
    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Oh ! thanks your idea .So how to pass a variable from js to php.??
EX: i want to use  variable "sv_id" from js to call it my file php??

Comment: By using jQuery ajax function you can easily pass the data to php. $.ajax({ url: // Route,
         data: {sv_id: sv_id},
         type: 'GET',
         success: function(output) {
                      alert(output);
                  }
});

Comment: You may get some idea if you look over this tutorial.
 Thanks. [http://www.expertphp.in/article/laravel-5-ajax-crud-example-to-build-web-application-without-page-refresh]

Comment: Sorry ! This link is died .(Error 404)

Comment: Please look over some tutorial on jQuery Ajax & PHP in google or youtube. I think, you'll be able to get some idea. Thanks.